Collapsed Main Menu (Hamburger Menu) - What setting, addon or modifier is this from?
It's Blender 4.2 / Mac:

Blender's main menu is displayed as a hamburger menu at the top left of the screen and the menu items are located in a submenu. I did it quite some time ago and find it quite useful.
But, now I don't remember how I got it. I looked through all the addons where it's working and nothing came up.
Anyone recognize this or where it's from or how to add it?
Thanks

What do you mean "this"? the fact that the Blender window header menus are condensed into a hamburger menu?

I think what you are looking for is explained here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/buttons/menus.html#collapsing-menus

Yep, that.  Thanks. If not for the -1, I'd flag this as the solution.  Oh well.

@unkerjay 1. Anyone can downvote your question, so it is not necessarily the one offering the solution. "Punishing" people answering your question because someone downvoted it will not get you very far on this site. 2. You can only accept answers in the answers section, not comments - so it does not matter if you refuse to accept it just because are huffy about the downvote. And honestly it is a poorly asked question, you did not put the image into the question and actually you do not tell what "this" is you are asking about. curious_t made a good guess.

Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Simply right-clicking on the header and chooseing Header -> Show Menus should work on MacOS same as on Windows:

